# Interpreting Augmented Dickey-Fuller in R

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, interpretation, unit-root

I know that this has been discussed before, but those discussions did not really answer my questions. I know how the ADF test works, but I am having trouble interpreting the output for the three options using the `ur.df` function in R (package: `urca`). Could someone walk me through the interpretations?
More specifically, what are `tau1`, `tau2`, `phi1`, `phi2`, and `phi3`?

```
summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="none",selectlags="BIC"))
summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="drift",selectlags="BIC"))
summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="trend",selectlags="BIC"))

> summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="none",selectlags="BIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression none 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-95.199 -23.380  -6.608  26.885  86.560 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
z.lag.1     0.04398    0.01205   3.650  0.00183 **
z.diff.lag -0.03722    0.24417  -0.152  0.88053   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 45 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7091,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6768 
F-statistic: 21.94 on 2 and 18 DF,  p-value: 1.492e-05


Value of test-statistic is: 3.6495 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.66 -1.95  -1.6

> summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="drift",selectlags="BIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression drift 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-69.366 -24.625  -3.018  34.165  82.227 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -75.21181   45.89715  -1.639   0.1196  
z.lag.1       0.09756    0.03467   2.814   0.0119 *
z.diff.lag   -0.20396    0.25469  -0.801   0.4343  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 43.03 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3596,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2843 
F-statistic: 4.773 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.02264


Value of test-statistic is: 2.814 8.6258 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.75 -3.00 -2.63
phi1  7.88  5.18  4.12

> summary(ur.df(tcm.ts, type="trend",selectlags="BIC"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-86.46 -14.84   5.56  20.87  70.29 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  91.4039    92.1407   0.992   0.3360  
z.lag.1      -0.1127     0.1082  -1.042   0.3129  
tt           13.0810     6.4318   2.034   0.0589 .
z.diff.lag   -0.1287     0.2369  -0.543   0.5946  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 39.54 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4911,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3957 
F-statistic: 5.148 on 3 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.01109


Value of test-statistic is: -1.042 8.1902 6.7579 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.38 -3.60 -3.24
phi2  8.21  5.68  4.67
phi3 10.61  7.24  5.91
```

Comment: you have to start your testing procedure with a trend and a drift. then your remove the trend, and finally the drift.